# What is the "Calamity of Thursday"?

Tags: hadith, history

I was reading some hadith and I pass by this:

> 114 حدثنا يحيى بن سليمان قال حدثني ابن وهب قال أخبرني يونس عن ابن شهاب
>   عن عبيد الله بن عبد الله عن ابن عباس قال لما اشتد بالنبي صلى الله عليه
>   وسلم وجعه قال ائتوني بكتاب أكتب لكم كتابا لا تضلوا بعده قال عمر إن
>   النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم غلبه الوجع وعندنا كتاب الله حسبنا فاختلفوا
>   وكثر اللغط قال قوموا عني ولا ينبغي عندي التنازع  فخرج ابن عباس يقول إن
>   الرزية كل الرزية ما حال بين رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم وبين كتابه
>
> source:http://hadith.al-islam.com/Page.aspx?pageid=192&BookID=24&PID=115

> Narrated by 'Ubaidullah bin 'Abdullah
>
> Ibn 'Abbas said, "When the
>   ailment of the Prophet became worse, he said, 'Bring for me (writing)
>   paper and I will write for you a statement after which you will not go
>   astray.' But 'Umar said, 'The Prophet is seriously ill, and we have
>   got Allah's Book with us and that is sufficient for us.' But the
>   companions of the Prophet differed about this and there was a hue and
>   cry. On that the Prophet said to them, 'Go away (and leave me alone).
>   It is not right that you should quarrel in front of me." Ibn 'Abbas
>   came out saying, "It was most unfortunate (a great disaster) that
>   Allah's Apostle was prevented from writing that statement for them
>   because of their disagreement and noise.
>
> source: http://www.sahih-bukhari.com/Pages/Bukhari_1_03.php

And this is called "Calamity of Thursday" So i have those questions:

- What is the story of this day?
- what happens?
- and why it's called like that?

Comment: @Sayyid - This is a rather contentious hadith that is usually known as *hadith razziatul khamis* (the hadith of the Thursday crisis). It has been the fuel of several Sunni/Shi'a flame wars so I haven't answered. Yet.

Comment: can someone provide a link to an english translation of this hadith. i viewed the link in google translate and there is no mention of a 'thursday' in the [google-translated page](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ar&tl=en&u=http://hadith.al-islam.com/Page.aspx%3Fpageid%3D192%26BookID%3D24%26PID%3D115&sandbox=0&usg=ALkJrhgPcm2xkuG9zDba3U3kf0jmXC1etg).

Comment: @MAKZ I insert the English say Bro

Comment: The hadith is OK. it is clear that prophet wanted to give some statemet, but didnot because the companions were at quarrel.  but where do you find this is called "Hinge on Thursday"?

Comment: I translated to english It's called in Arabic رزية يوم الخميس. Maybe translation is not perfect but if you serach for Arabic name you can find it.

Comment: Can't speak for the accuracy of the translation, but Wikipedia refers to it as the "[Calamity of Thursday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith_of_the_pen_and_paper)"

Comment: "Hue and cry" is a deprecated and no longer idiomatic phrase; if you want to understand this passage better as read in English I would recommend that you find a more recent translation of it.

Answer (score 3):

Muhammad became ill in the year 632 and his health took a serious turn on a **Thursday**<sup>([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith_of_the_pen_and_paper))</sup>. On that day, prophet wanted to give some statemet, but didnot because the companions were at quarrel, as stated in the hadith you quoted.

Both shia and sunni respect this hadith. But it is known as رزية يوم الخميس (The Calamity of Thursday) among shias.

- What is the story of this day?  - you have already mentioned the hadith.
- what happens?
  'Ubaidullah said: Ibn Abbas used to say:

  > There was a **heavy loss, indeed a heavy loss**, that, due to their dispute and noise. Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) **could not write** (or dictate) the document for them. [[ref](http://sunnah.com/muslim/25/31)]
- why it's called like that?
  The Hadith is called *The Calamity of Thursday*, Because, as we can see, *the heavy Loss* occurred on a *Thursday*.

For further reading, please visit [this page](http://www.al-islam.org/al-murajaat-shii-sunni-dialogue-sharaf-al-din-al-musawi/letter-86#ii-reason-why-prophet-repealed-his-order-then)